# Input type='tel' not showing phonepad on iPad webapp

Tags: html, ios, ipad, reactjs

```html
<input id="cell-input" required onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.addDashes(this.state.phone)}
               name="cell" placeholder="012-345-6789" type="tel" autocomplete="off"
               autoFocus class="hairline text_400 field_type_a field_ph1" />
```

The markup is a bit different, as it's a react-template being used with reactjs.

As is, this brings up the numeric keypad instead of the phonepad, but only for iOS (I don't actually have an iPhone for testing, so maybe just for iPad as far as I know). I've also tried adding a pattern like "\d*", but to no avail. I still just get the numeric keypad.

Reading this, I assume it should be working for anything iOS - https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I get the same problem, I am assuming if you can't make calls on it, then the tel keypad won't show. (I don't have an iphone either to test)

Comment: I was able to test using my boss's iPhone, and it showed the phone pad. I guess this is an iPad thing. My solution is to create a custom phone pad with react. I can control the aesthetic this way as well. Still... this issue has been a bit frustrating.